# WebBrowsable vs Personalizable in Web Parts

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

What is the difference between the attributes `WebBrowsable` and `Personalizable` in a Sharepoint 2010 web part?

e.g.

```
[Personalizable(), WebBrowsable]
public string IconURL { get; set; }
```

vs

```
[WebBrowsable]
public string IconURL { get; set; }
```

MSDN gives the impression that `personalizable` is per user, whereas `webbrowseable` is for all users - however it doesn't explicitly mention this and I would like to get this sorted in my head.

E.g. can I set a user specific property on `personalizable` and web-part wide on `webbrowsable`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [WebBrowseable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webbrowsableattribute.aspx) attribute specifies that the decorated property should appear in the editor component of the web part. It only allows the end user to modify the property and does nothing about persistence.

The [Personalizable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.personalizableattribute.aspx) attribute specifies that the value of the decorated property must be persisted in the SharePoint backend, either in the user store (by default) or in the shared store (if the `Shared` scope is specified). It only cares about persistence and does nothing about the property presence in the editor component.

So, if you decorate a property with `[WebBrowsable]` and not `[Personalizable]`, the end user will be able to modify it in the editor component but its new value won't be persisted.

Conversely, if you decorate a property with `[Personalizable]` and not `[WebBrowsable]`, its value will be persisted but the end user won't be allowed to modify it.

Comment: So when you set the attribute to `WebPartStorage(Storage.Shared)` the settings should be persisted for all users, wheras `WebPartStorage(Storage.Personal),` is only for one user?

Comment: @JD, yes. [[`WebPartStorage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpartstorageattribute.aspx)] is the SharePoint Online equivalent to `[Personalizable]`.

Comment: Important to note that even if WebBrowseable is set to true you can still edit the property through a custom EditorPart.

Comment: Can you please take a look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23486587/persisting-custom-asp-net-webpart-properties.I hope you ll understand my question... @FrédéricHamidi

Answer (score 2):

WebBrowsable will make the property appear in the ToolPane or EditorPart of the WebPart.

Personalizable will allow the property to be stored and persisted in the personalization store. There is an enum in which you can specify weather this property will store per user values or a single value for all users.

WebBrowsable is also property specific as Personalizable.

Comment: Can you please take a look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23486587/persisting-custom-asp-net-webpart-properties.I hope you ll understand my question...

Answer (score 1):

WebBrowsable [WebBrowsable(True)]
"Indicates whether the designated property of a Web Parts control is displayed in a PropertyGridEditorPart object." (MSDN)
http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webbrowsableattribute.aspx

Personalizable [Personalizable(true)]
Allows users the ability to personalize settings for the WebPart.
http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.personalizableattribute.aspx